# Apollo client: extract data from promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue.js application where I'm trying to perform the following call:

```
const data = this.$apollo
    .query({
      query: gql.getFoo,
      variables: {
        foo: bar
      }
    });
```

This returns a Promise instead of the actual data.

How can I extract the data from the promise?

I tried `const data = await this.$apollo.query(...)` but it didn't work.

Comment: `but it didn't work` why not? what did that give you as a result?

Comment: @JaromandaX I got an error `The 'await' operator can only be used in an 'async' function`

Comment: then make the function you're in `async` ... or you can use `this.$apollo.query(...).then(data => { /* use data here */ })`

Comment: You can extract data from promise using 
```
data.then(data => { console.log(data )});
```
first data is promise
second is data returned in promise